# From Nashorn to Graaljs

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, graalvm

I would like to add the latest ECMAScript support to my java application. I currently use Java 8 with the Nashorn engine. How could I switch to Graaljs?

this is the code I should translate:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;
private ScriptEngine engine;
engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine("-scripting");
...
engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

GraalVM has an example project for this very purpose https://github.com/graalvm/graal-js-jdk11-maven-demo

It is generally recommended to use the [GraalVM Polyglot API](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/package-frame.html), but there is a compatibility with the script engine as well. The example project does the following:

```
ScriptEngine graaljsEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
```

Comment: I wanted to follow this guide: https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/NashornMigrationGuide.md


I would like to use ployglot, but I can't understand how I could insert my old "bindings".

Comment: There is a section on binding in the Context javadoc that might be helpful https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html